# Suite CRM: Can't resize my dashlet

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

When I click on edit dashlet (default ones and customized) an error eppears:

> There was an error handling this request.

I tried to use SuiteCRM 7.5, 7.5.1 and 7.5.3 and all of them give the same issue.

[image: Error message screenshot]

Comment: You should log this as an issue on the suitecrm's issue tracker: https://github.com/salesagility/SuiteCRM/issues